# How to switch forms in C# using a button event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some code here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Run(new Form3());
}
```

Although I don't think this is how you are meant to change forms, when I ran it, it threw an error stating:

> Starting a second message loop on a
>   single thread is not a valid operation

Comment: How about just `(new Form3()).Show()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method to switch between forms in C# ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741699/whats-the-best-method-to-switch-between-forms-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `Application.Run` - that is for starting windows form application (internal message loop which is shared among all forms in the application), not for showing a form. Each form has `Show` and `Hide` method so you should simply call:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f = new Form3(); // This is bad
    f.Show();
}
```

But you should not create form each time you want to show it. If you want to have only one instance of the form you should keep it as global and only show or hide it on demand. Otherwise you will have to call `Close` instead of `Hide` to clear all resources the form consumes.

Answer (score 2):

you can do as simple as it is :

```
test mp = new test();
mp.Text = " Welcome Mr." + textBox1.Text;
this.Hide();
mp.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

where test is your new form 
and then if you wona pass variables to the other form just make you variable as public then you can make :

```
 mp.Text = " Welcome Mr." + textBox1.Text;
```

then showdialog to show your new form and close the old form..

Answer (score 1):

Your first form should create the second form on the first usage and hide itself from view. Then the second form will hide itself and show the first form when you switch back. Something like this...

```
  private Form _firstForm;
  private Form _secondForm;

  private void switchToSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
      if (_secondForm == null)
          _secondForm = new SecondForm();

      Hide();
      _secondForm.Show();
  }

  private void switchToFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
      Hide();
      _firstForm.Show();
  }
```

You would assign to *firstForm* the *this* value inside the constructor of the first form class and because this is the main form it will always be created at application startup. If you want to save resources you could also dispose of the second form when you switch back to the first and so recreate it each time you switch.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
this.Hide(); // Hide the current form.

Menu menu = new Menu(); // Create new instance of the new form.

menu.Show(); // Show it
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `Form1` and `Form2`
Your scope is not clear if you want

1. Switch between `Form1` and `Form2` and keep both of them alive.
2. Keep only either `Form1`  or `Form2` at a time.

for case 1 simple `Form1.Hide() and Form2.Show()` would be adequate.

for case 2 the solution will be a little bit complicated.

1. Create your own instance of `ApplicationContext MyAppCxt= new ApplicationContext()`.
2. instead of the default `Program.Run(Form1)` call `Program.Run(MyAppCxt(Form1))`
3. in the handler of some event, when you need to switch the `Form1` and `Form2`

   `Form2 f2 = new Form2();//Create the new form
   MyAppCxt.MainForm = f2;//set Form2 as MainForm in the message queue
   Form2.Close()//Close Form2 and release all the resource 
   F2.Show();//display Form2 to the user`

the same scenario would be repeated when required to switch back between `Form2` and `Form1`